# C++ -- STL Vector::const_iterator why not use < xx.end()?

Tags: c++

```
   // display vector elements using const_iterator
   for ( constIterator = integers.begin();
      constIterator != integers.end(); ++constIterator )
      cout << *constIterator << ' ';
```

Can we use `constIterator < integers.end()`?

Thank you

Comment: Your question title makes for a good comment: "why use `<` xx.end()" -- Why indeed?!? `!=` seems perfectly fine when we're already dealing with iterators. (As opposed to indexes, where `<` sometimes makes sense.)

Comment: It's a good idea to cache end(), rather than calling it throughout a loop.

Comment: @Martin: I don't see a real difference between indexes and iterators here. (Basically, their only difference is in how to access the referred to element.) There is (or used to be, I'm not sure what happened to it) a school of thought, coined _defensive programming_, which preferred `<` and `>` over `==` and `!=`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091380/4091557#4091557).

Comment: Hello Martin, I have corrected the title -- thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`operator<` is only defined for *[random access iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/)*. These are provided, for example, by `std::vector` and `std::string`, containers that, in essence, store their data in contiguous storage, where iterators are usually little more than wrapped pointers. Iterators provided by, e.g., `std::list` are only *[bidirectional iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/)*, which only provide comparison for equality.

Traditionally, it's seen as *defensive programming* to use `<` instead of `!=`. In case of errors (for example, someone changes `++i` to `i+=2`) the loop will terminate even though the exact end value is never reached. However, another view at this is that it might mask an error, while the loop running endlessly or causing a crash would make the error apparent.

Comment: Wouldn't `i += 2` be undefined behavior if `i` is incremented beyond `end()`?

Comment: @UncleBens: Yes, for iterators this would be _UB_ anyway. I was referring to the general idea of doing this. Think "index".

Comment: Wouldn't it also be UB for pointers - to not point to NULL, any valid object or "just past" any valid object?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, and you can also use operator < for deque::(const_)iterator, but it won't work for iterators for any other containers.

The working of operator < is guaranteed because vector and deque provide a Random Access Iterator.

Comment: Hello Martin, Or we can say that < works for vector b/c vector uses continuous memory?

Comment: That's *how* it works for vector (the iterator is just a pointer), but not how it works for deque (I'm fairly sure deques are discontinuous).

Comment: Deques store their data in chunks, and therefore in _almost_ continuous memory. That's why they can provide random access iterators.

Comment: @sbi, yes, an STL deque is something like this: http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/articles/deque.html